# Is there a way to save just one file in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

My traditional workflow must be a little different to the PHPStorm default. I often work on multiple files at the same time and want to be able to save just one file when I've finished with it, without saving the others that I've modified.

I've managed to turn off the auto-save feature. Now, when I edit files I get stars on the ones I've edited and they stay like that until I hit 'save'. So far so good.

But when press CTRL-S to save, expecting it to save the one file I'm looking at so I can go back to the ones with asterisks to polish them off too, it also saves ALL the other files too.

I hope there's some way to change this behaviour or set up something to allow me to save just one file at a time!

Comment: Out of interest, are you still using Phpstorm? I am trying demos of Phpstorm 8 and Komodo. To be frank, I find Komodo a lot nicer to use, primarily because I can save single files. I cannot see the logic of having to save everything each time.

Comment: I am still using PhpStorm - and judging by the show of hands at the recent SymfonyLiveLondon conference it seems that it's a *very* popular choice amongst Symfony developers (and the Symfony plug in is very good). P.S. I gave it a good 6 months but still couldn't see the benefit of not being able to save a single document, so I now use the keybinding from the answer below.

Comment: Yes it does seem very popular. Thats the main reason I haven't discounted it yet.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**[Yes, you can](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-98513)** .. but that still does not change a lot (e.g if you change your settings, or run/re-run something -- all files will be saved automatically anyway). Eventually (after few weeks or month of adaptation) you will get used to this behaviour and quite likely will love it (yes, this means changing working habits a bit, which is quite hard to do (requires time) for some people/in some cases).

**Anyway** ... to enable "save single file" functionality:

1. `Settings | Keymap`
2. On that screen, in search box type "`save`"
3. The action you are after is called **"Other | Save Document"**
4. Assign whatever shortcut you want.

[image]

**P.S.**
This action will NOT ask for [confirmation](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6460) (same behaviour as standard save does).

**P.P.S.**
This action is available since PhpStorm v7 ONLY.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up that this is coming in PhpStorm 7. I couldn't find any keymaps for this in 6.x.  I've been using PhpStorm for more than a month now and still not used to it saving everything... maybe I'll get there in the end, but we'll see if 7.x comes out first!

Comment: EAP builds: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Early+Access+Program

Comment: Happy to see [JetBrains finally implemented this, after I bugged them for over a year about it](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-98513).

Comment: Actually there is a setting to disable automatic saving too. `Appearance & Behavior | System Settings | Save files on frame deactivation & Save files automatically if application is idle for.. `

Comment: @diynevala That's a completely different story. That works only when leaving IDE window. That option does not do anything if you click on "Run" button, execute any command in Terminal, accept changes made in Settings and other cases -- all files will be saved (and most of them are absolutely expected behaviour and were asked to be implemented this way by actual users).

Comment: I'm starting to passionately hate PHPStorm for this non-standard behavior.

Comment: @aross Got used to such behaviour/workflow in 2 months or even less time (around 7 years ago now). Currently I do not have ANY issues or regrets in this regard -- looks pretty natural to me (got used to?). But yes -- in other apps that I often use (like Notepad++ / Delphi / SSMS) such behaviour would be inconvenient (but then -- usage pattern is different -- never tried such approach there). Plus, it may also greatly depend on your correct coding workflow (what tools/techniques used etc) -- in some cases having multiple related files in a "good state" is not always possible...

Comment: One of the things that becomes impossible is having a couple of lines of code in a file unsaved, create a commit with some other changes (potentially in the same file), then save the file again and create a new commit. For these and other reasons, I often make changes to a file that **shouldn't** be saved right away

Comment: @LazyOne I have not been able to tame PHPStorm in the past half year and have reverted to using Atom. I have all the tools that were useful from PHPStorm as packages and it works a treat. And no funny "we know what's better for you" proprietary IDE behavior. Atom gets out of my way in that regard, while PHPStorm was an obstacle. The worst obstacle of all IDEs I have used.

Comment: "Eventually (after few weeks or month of adaptation) you will get used to this behaviour and quite likely will love it". Been using PhpStorm for about 2 years now and still haven't gotten used to the wonky saving behavior.