# PhpStorm 5 saving watches and a single file

Tags: debugging, ide, phpstorm

I have two questions on PhpStorm 5.

1) Can Watches be saved along with a debug configuration, so I don't have to re-create them every time I close and re-open the software? I have noticed that watches may be deleted by the software even during a working session.

2) Is there a way to save just a single file instead of saving all of the open files (only 'Save All' function exists).

Answer (score 1):

1. <s>**Unfortunately No.** Watches got deleted as soon as debug tool window is closed.</s>

Corresponding ticket: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-42954

**UPDATE:** Yes, this is now possible as of version **10** or so -- the aforementioned ticket has been implemented so all watches are now saved together with Run/Debug Configuration that was used to launch the debug.

2. **Yes, you can -- but only since PhpStorm v7.** *But that still makes little to **no difference*** as all other files will be saved anyway on standard occasion (change setting; run/re-run something etc -- same logic as before -- you cannot close editor tab and reject all changes automatically or be asked if file must be saved or not).

More details in this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19147691/783119